# Prove $\sum \frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3 + 2}}$ diverges.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I attempted both the ratio test and the root test, and both proved inconclusive.

Wolfram tells me that the improper integral from $[1, \infty)$ diverges. However, I am unsure how to integrate the function by hand.

Is there another test I can use? Or is there a simple way to integrate the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\dfrac{3n}{\sqrt{n^{3}+2}}\geq\dfrac{3n}{\sqrt{n^{3}+2n^{3}}}=\dfrac{3n}{3^{1/2}n^{3/2}}=\dfrac{3^{1/2}}{n^{1/2}}$, and $\displaystyle\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{n^{1/2}}=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Try limit comparison with 
$$\frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3}}$$
by finding the limit as 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3+2}}\frac{\sqrt{n^3}}{3n}$$
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test